# the command or action 'GoToRecord' isn't available now Accde Database

Tags: ms-access

I  have a problem with a continuous form producing this error  the command or action 'GoToRecord' isn't available now, This is the form source:

```
SELECT Bom.productcode, Bom.code, Bom.Item, Bom.cons, Bom.BomNumber, [Item Names].Type, Bom.Remarks FROM [Item Names] INNER JOIN Bom ON [Item Names].code = Bom.code WHERE (((Bom.productcode)=Forms!FrmNewPo!t0) And ((Bom.BomNumber)=Forms!FrmNewPo!Bom));
```

This Error Happens when I press a command button with this code on click event:

```
Private Sub Command204_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Robot"
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Forms![Robot]![PONumber] = Me.T7
Forms![Robot]![productcode] = Me.t0
Forms![Robot]![OrderQty] = Me.T3
Forms![Robot]![zdate] = Me.T6
Forms![Robot]![Mold] = Me.Mold
Forms![Robot]![Machine] = Me.Machine
Forms![Robot]![Status] = Me.Status
Forms![Robot]![ProductBomNum] = Me.Bom
DoCmd.Close

Dim sql As DAO.Recordset
Set sql = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TblPoMaterials", dbOpenDynaset)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst    ' I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE
For m = 1 To T8

With sql
.AddNew
!PONumber = T7
!MaterialCode = Code1
!MaterialName = T1
!ProductionDate = T6
!Shift = "none"
!cons = T2
!AdditionPercent = Text324
!MaterialType = Text300
!OrderQty = T3
.Update
End With
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Next m
MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, "Saved successfully"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
t0 = ""
T6 = ""
T7 = ""
T3 = ""
T10 = ""
T10 = ""
Status = ""
BomCombo = ""
Me.ComboMachine = ""
Me.ComboMold = ""
Mold = ""
Machine = ""
T216 = ""
Me.Requery
```

The robot form appends the header of the form to a table, the SQL appends the detail part to some other table. When the error happened I found the header in the first table but the detail part isn't found in the other table so I suspected the line in the code is causing this problem but I don't know why!

I tried another approach as following:

```
Private Sub Command204_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Robot"
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Forms![Robot]![PONumber] = Me.T7
Forms![Robot]![productcode] = Me.t0
Forms![Robot]![OrderQty] = Me.T3
Forms![Robot]![zdate] = Me.T6
Forms![Robot]![Mold] = Me.Mold
Forms![Robot]![Machine] = Me.Machine
Forms![Robot]![Status] = Me.Status
Forms![Robot]![ProductBomNum] = Me.Bom
DoCmd.Close

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
For m = 1 To T8
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QryAppendMat2"

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Next m
MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, "Saved successfully"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
t0 = ""
T6 = ""
T7 = ""
T3 = ""
'T5 = ""
T10 = ""
T10 = ""
Status = ""
BomCombo = ""
Me.ComboMachine = ""
Me.ComboMold = ""
Mold = ""
Machine = ""
T216 = ""
Me.Requery
```

The QryAppendMat2 is an append query which does the same job as the previous SQL Statement the code as following:

```
INSERT INTO TblPoMaterials ( PONumber, MaterialCode, MaterialName, Cons, MaterialType, ProductionDate, Shift, AdditionPercent, OrderQty )
SELECT [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![T7] AS Expr1, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![Code1] AS Expr2, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![T1] AS Expr3, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![T2] AS Expr6, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![Text300] AS Expr8, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![T6] AS Expr4, "none" AS Expr5, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![Text324] AS Expr7, [Forms]![FrmNewPo]![T3] AS Expr9;
```

But the same problem happened And I don't know why.
I have some Remarks :
-The problem happens in the accde with linked tables not with the accdb database.
-The problem happens one time of five , Meaning it works fine sometimes and other times just don't.
-The same conditions exactly could proceed normally after the problem happens when I try it again.

I need some help guys and so sorry for long question, but I tried to cover all possible questions.

Comment: Are you using UNBOUND form?

Comment: Yes I am , Unbound Form

Comment: Okay, why not BOUND form?

Comment: Because it gets its data from different sources , And append data to different sources , with certain conditions , Lets say i have to go this way and keep it unbound .

Comment: Sounds like should be using form/subform arrangment.

Comment: An intermittent issue is nearly impossible to analyze. If I can't replicate, can't offer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like should be using form/subform arrangment. – June7 43 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

me.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext